# Hierarchical models: Estimating variance and combining two estimators

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood, estimators, hierarchical-bayesian

Assume that $y_i \sim N(50,10)$.

I observe a signal with additive Gaussian noise $s_i \sim N(y_i, \sigma_d^2)$

I observe $n$ such signals, each corresponding to a different $y_i$.

I want to estimate $\sigma_d$. I am not exactly sure how to since most of the textbooks / posts discuss how to estimate the parameters of the distribution of $y_i$ (which are known in this case).
My calculations suggest that the variance of the signals: $\sum(s_i-\bar s_i)^2/n$ should be equal to $\sigma_d^2 + 10$, (where $10$ is the variance of $y_i$), so the estimator for $\sigma_d^2$ is $\sum(s_i-\bar s_i)^2/n - 10$. Is this correct? What if $\sum(s_i-\bar s_i)^2/n < 10?$

Additionally, if I have an estimator for $\sigma_d^2$ from another source, I believe the best way to combine the information from the 2 estimators is to take a weighted average, with the weights being in inverse ratio of the variance of the estimators. How do I get the variance of this estimator?
I feel like this should be trivial but I am not sure how to go about it. Any help would be great. Thank you in advance!